# update php5 install

Tags: php, apt-get

Good Day.

I'm running Debian php 5.2.6-1+lenny9. When I initially configured the server, I ran the apt-get with php5-mysql php5-gd, among other others.

Somehow I didn't install with php-curl and I need that library. So my question: If I just run

```
apt-get php5-curl
```

what's going to happen? I have live sites on the sever. Will this just recompile php5 with the added curl library, or will it basically give a fresh install with only curl and not mysql, and gd, etc.

Comment: that depends on how did you install php

Comment: I installed Debian 5 via CD, then apache2, then ran `apt-get install php5 php5-mysql php-gd` etc (I can dig up full command line if need be). Is that enough info?

Comment: in that case you can simply run  ____apt-get install php5-curl____. After that, check in php ini if it is loaded. If not, add it to loaded extensions

Comment: Thanks. So there is an underscore at the end of the `php5-curl` command?

Comment: nope, i've made a mistake, i will correct it: ___apt-get install php5-curl___

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get install php5-curl` will install binary packages, no compiling involved. It will also automatically restart apache so the new module will be available in your php scripts.

Oh, and if you are unsure about what you are doing, don't do it on a production system! Set up an additional Test server.